# Redis - many operations when using Redis.StackExchange

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a redis server in Azure with these clients connected:

[image: clients connected]

Overall stat for my server is:

[image: Overall stats]
Two questions

1) I have only done one capacity test on it, so it is ok that the numops and overall operations is high, what i dont understand is, that right now there is no one on the server still i get like 2-9 operations pr. second. It looks like it is only PINGs and INFO and some AUTHs, which is fine but is this normal, to receive these PINGs so often? I can see that I might get pings and auths because I have many clients, which leads me to question 2:

2) the client list: there is 7 clients. One of them is my admin, the 6 others is from one server (I have checked the IPs). Is it normal that I see so many connections? I thought that only one was going to be created. The way i create the Redis connection is to instaniate it in my Startup.cs:

```
...
RedisConnectorHelper.Init(storageSettings);
...
```

RedisConnectorHelper.cs:

```
public static class RedisConnectorHelper
{
    public static void Init(StorageSettings storageSettings)
    {
        _lazyConnection = new Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer>(() =>
        {
            return ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(storageSettings.RedisCache);
        });
    }

    private static Lazy<ConnectionMultiplexer> _lazyConnection;

    public static ConnectionMultiplexer Connection
    {
        get
        {
            return _lazyConnection.Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it normal to see 5 clients to one server? Or am I doing something wrong? I have one asp.net core project, with one Startup.cs, that instantiate one connection. This project is deployed to one Azure webapp. Shouldn't I just see one client in the list?

I am fairly new to Redis.StackExchange (and Redis), so maybe i am misunderstanding something. Or maybe I am using both technologies wrong.

Redis server is a S1 in Azure.

Comment: Is your Azure webapp scaling out?

Comment: @devNull it has done, from one to two instances, but that was this thursday, and it has scaled in again. Maybe it hasn't been destroyed?